# Testing with google and cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

Colleagues !

I try to write simple application with google test and cmake. I do as written in documentation. My CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (foo_d-google-test)
add_executable (foo_d-google-test main.cpp)
enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
if (NOT GTest_FOUND) 
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find Google Test Framework!")
endif()
```

and main.cpp is

```
#include <math.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST (SquareRootTest, PositiveNos) {
    EXPECT_EQ (18.0, sqrt (324.0));
    EXPECT_EQ (25.4, sqrt (645.16));
    EXPECT_EQ (50.3321, sqrt (2533.310224));
}

TEST (SquareRootTest, ZeroAndNegativeNos) {
    ASSERT_EQ (0.0, sqrt (0.0));
    ASSERT_EQ (-1, sqrt (-22.0));
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    int ret = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    return ret;
 }
```

And I receive an error

> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
>     Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)

My platform is Debian Linux 9, and library googletest was installed. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295876/cmake-cannot-find-a-googletest-required-library

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot copy libraries into target directory.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but be careful using assertions and floating-point numbers. your `SquareRootTest` should be using the [appropriate assertions for floating-point numbers](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#floating-point-comparison).